# My rvm install script works and apparently uses rvm correctly but a new/reloaded bash fails with a syntax error

Tags: bash, scripting, rvm

I wrote this script https://gist.github.com/1313611 to ease my installs for rvm. The whole script simply installs rvm, installs 1.9.2, rails and creates a default gemset. All of that works and I can verify that inside the .rvm folder. However after installing a I get:

```
bash: ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm: line 14: syntax error near unexpected token `do'
bash: ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm: line 14: `  do'
```

I've also tried using `curl -sB`. I'm guessing it has to do with my environment but can't seem to figure out the problem (obviously, ha).

Thanks for any input

CLARIFICATION: I'm on an Fedora 14 Desktop - I have it working with no edits to my script on a shared hosting account at Dreamhost.

Not sure it helps (planning to dig into a bit more) but the computer it fails on is managed by the school which means the Home dir I install to is on NFS. Another environment oddity is that the default shell (ypchsh won't let me change yet [working with boss to change]) is tcsh, but I always run bash when I open a terminal. I'm thinking this last bit is a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BLAST - Apparently there was a script being loaded that is basically a universal bashrc for our school where someone set and alias to 'for' because it had something to do with fortran.

So I just copied that rc to my directory to fix up that alias and now reference that file rather than the universal rc.

Well we learned something today - when in this much doubt check all aliases.